# Entity Framework - Saving by passing foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an entity called Device which belongs to a User entity, so the Device has a property of type User. When I save the Device, how can I specify the User to which it belongs, without making a query to the database for the User.

```
        var d = new Device();
        d.ApplicationVersion = dm.ApplicationVersion;
        d.DeviceId = dm.DeviceId;
        d.DeviceName = dm.DeviceName;
        d.User = context.Users.First(u => u.Id == userId);
        context.Add(d);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Maybe saying d.User = new User(){Id = userId} and EF being smart about it, but it seems a bit hacked.

Comment: An easiest way is to have an explicit property in the `Device` class, the `IdUser`, `UserId` or whatever else you name it and have an explicit mapping (using an attribute or fluent mapping) that tells EF this is the foreign key column. You just then set the value of this column instead of assigning a reference to the parent object. Don't have the compiler at hand but this should work.

Comment: You could also new up a user and set it's entity state: `context.Entry(d.User).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`